# High gas consumption when using `staticcall` on a non-view/pure function

Tags: solidity, static-call

Even though functions called with `staticcall` cannot modify the state, I ran into an issue when (accidentally) calling a non-view/pure function using `staticcall`. For example, using this contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.3;

contract TestContract {
  address public foo;
  
  function setFoo(address _foo) external {
    foo = _foo;
  }
  
  function doFoo(address _target, address _foo) external returns (bool success) {
    (success,) = _target.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setFoo(address)", _foo));
  }
}
```

Calling `doFoo()` in Remix, with the contract address of `TestContract` as `_target`, and another random address as `_foo`, the total gas consumption is 2,953,792. The gas limit is set to 3,000,000. Changing the gas limit to 30,000,000 will result in a gas consumption of about 29 million gas, so it looks like it´s using up the entire gas limit.

Why does `staticcall` have this behaviour?

Comment: When an opcode that modifies storage is executed within a staticcall it will generate an error and consume all available gas inside the staticcall. It was the standard behavior until revert opcode was introduced.